# Show a function defined on rationals integrable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, functions, riemann-integration

Let q1,q2,... be a fixed enumeration of rationals in [0,1]. Define f(x) so
 $f(q_n)=a_n $
for all a and 0 otherwise. Prove that it is Riemann integrable if the sequence an approaches 0, and justify will it be integrable if the sequence doesn’t approach 0.

Here I would know how to prove if there is a finite no of rationals by using epsilon lengths of rectangale, but unfortunately it is infinite.

Comment: Do you mean $f(q_n)=a\cdot n$ or $f(q_n)=a_n$? You haven't explain your use of the letter $a$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm it would mean $f(q_n)=a_n$

Comment: It is not possible to prove that it is Riemann integrable, because in many cases it won't be. For example, if $a_n=1$ for all $n$, then $f$ is discontinuous at all points. Riemann can't handle that many discontinuities. Did the problem contain some additional information? For example: $a_n\to0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$0$ is always a possible Riemann sum no matter what the partition, so the only hope the function has of being integrable is if the integral is $0$.

Therefore you need to show for each $\varepsilon$ there is a $\delta$ such that every Riemann sum for a partition that is finer than $\delta$ is absolutely less than $\varepsilon$. A natural strategy is to budget some of the $\varepsilon$ to contributions from infinitely many *small* $a_n$, and the rest to intervals that contain finitely many *large* function values.

So since we're assuming $a_n\to 0$ we can find $N$ such that $|a_n| < \varepsilon/2$ for $n\ge N$. This bounds the contributions for "small" $a_n$s to $\varepsilon/2$. Can you show that there must be a $\delta$ such that the first $N$ $a_n$s together cannot contribute more than $\varepsilon/2$ to the Riemann sum?

---

In the case that $a_n\not\to 0$, you can't say anything in general about integrability. To wit, $$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{when }x=1/k\text{ for some }k\in\mathbb N_+ \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$
is Riemann integrable, but
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{when }x=(2m+1)/2k\text{ for some }m,k\in\mathbb N_+ \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$
is not.

Comment: Although the a_n becomes smaller than epsilon /2, why can we assume all their contributions be less than epsilon /2?

Comment: @2569cfa: They get multiplied by interval lengths, whose sum are $1$.

Comment: but wouldn’t there be infinite of them but epsilon will be constant

Comment: @2569cfa: Every Riemann sum samples only one value from each interval, so most of them will be ignored.

Comment: would this not make it less Rigourous? Although I see how this would make sense

Comment: @2569cfa: There's no particular lack of rigor. But note that I'm talking from the perspective of _discovering_ an argument that works, which is not in itself a rigorous activity. Once you have a particular reasoning in mind, you can start working on _writing it down_ with rigor. Then you wouldn't talk about the contribution of _all_ the small function values, but about the contributions from _those intervals in the partition where the chosen function value happens to be among the small ones_. Since there are only finitely many _intervals_ in the partition, nothing becomes infinite here.